# Configure orphanRemoval = true in Generate Entities of Table - JPA Tools - Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jpa

I'm having trouble every time I need to use the Generate Entities of Table from JPA Tools (use Eclipse Neon.3). I generate the entities with the Generate Entities of Table command from JPA Tools. In the code of a class in the annotation of a relationship I add the code orphanRemoval = true and saved everything right. When I need to use the Generate Entities of Table command again, when I look at the same class that I entered orphanRemoval = true, it no longer exists.

**How do I set up JPATools (on Generate Custom Entities screens) to insert orphanRemoval = true in a relationship so that it is memorized and every time I need to use the command to generate the table entities it automatically inserts orphanRemoval?**
Just like you select cascade on the Generate Custom Entities screen and it keeps memorized.

See the code snippet below: When you generate the entity with JPA Tools:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="pessoa", cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    private Set<PessoaContato> listaPessoaContato;
```

I enter manually in the code the orphanRemoval and saved:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="pessoa", cascade={CascadeType.ALL},orphanRemoval=true)
    private Set<PessoaContato> listaPessoaContato;
```

When I need to regenerate, jpa tools overwrite all classes by deleting everything that is entered manually, so the code snippet returns:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="pessoa", cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    private Set<PessoaContato> listaPessoaContato;
```